# Will wearing special outfits during smile time affect a child?

Tags: fallout-shelter

It appears that the children of two dwellers are some combination of the statistics of their parents. But do the outfits they are wearing at the time factored into their stats?

Answer (score 1):

No, as there is not a real correlation between parents and children at all. Only the C value seems to correlate a bit but this can be just luck.

If your dwellers wear a suit which improves C it will lower the time till smile time.

Comment: really? I put in two people with high Int and I get a child with above average int... I just dont know if the costumes affect it.

Comment: Well a friend of mine had noticed 10 births. Father high s, mother high s -> children has a bit higher p than normal. S was at the bottom. The only thing he has seen was that C was often higher if parents both have higher c. But there are some cases where this didn't matched top.

Answer (score -1):

I have had many births in my vault, and when i put Old Longfellow, 5 Strength 7 perception 8 endurance 4 charisma 6 intelligence 3 agility and 7 luck with my highest girls example: agility 5 with 2 or 1 everything else. i gave them outfits and bred and they got about a 4-6 everything. When i bred them without outfits that have +3-4 in stats, it changed it to a 3-6 stats three times in a row. Not a big difference, but it still works.